# Мне надо скрыть и показывать TabLayout с Tab- ами

Tags: android, view, android-tablayout

У менч есть  tab layout в  content_main.xml это код хмл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_main">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  /> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

и на нажатия на кнопку меняется основной fragment 
Вот мой код

```
 manager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                    R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(
                            R.id.content_main,
                            mapfragment)
                    .addToBackStack("tag").commit();

и я должен скрыть tablayout с табами вот как я делаю 

if(!mapcheck){
    MapFragment mapfragment = new MapFragment();
    manager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left,
            R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
            .replace(
                    R.id.content_main,
                    mapfragment)
            .addToBackStack("tag").commit();
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mapcheck=true;
    menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_view_list));
}else if(mapcheck){
    mapcheck=false;
    menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_near_me));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } });
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

но  вопрос в том что View.GONE работает а когда user возвращаеться назад на предыдущий fragment я должен показать табы но View.VISIBLE не работает пожалуйста помогите!!!

Comment: Здесь принято писать на русском языке

Comment: @pavlofff вот изменил,  я думал не на русском

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, открывая определенный фрагмент вы скрываете `TabLayout`, а закрывая его вы хотите показать вновь?

Comment: @McDaggen да именно так

Comment: @Serg ну тогда сделайте простое условие, if (такой то фрагмент активен) { tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); } else { tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE ); }

Comment: @McDaggen не у меня есть обработчик когда возвращаешся на передающий fragment, я проверил с логами но именно setvisible(View.VISIBLE)  не работает

Comment: Покажите код, где вы вызываете повторно этот метод

Comment: @McDaggen я поставил с низу

Comment: @McDaggen сделал